# Rename columns based on pattern R

Tags: r

I would like to rename multiple columns in a data frame with a function.

Data frame

```
nameAXX = c("car1", "car2", "car2", "car2", "car3", "car1") 
brand = c("b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b1")
productionAXX = c(10, 10, 10, 40, 10, 5) 
df = data.frame(brand, nameAXX, productionAXX)
```

The loop itself works but not if I wrap it in a function and call it.

```
replaceColNamePattern <- function(df, pattern, replace){
  for (name in colnames(df)){
    if (regexpr(pattern, name) > 0){
      names(df)[names(df)==name] <- gsub(pattern, replace, name)
    }
  }
}
```

Call function

```
replaceColNamePattern(adf, "AXX", "")
```

Is it not possible to rename the column within a function?

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop for this  Try with `grep` i.e. `gsub("AXX", "", names(df)[grep("AXX", names(df))])`

Comment: `names(adf) <- gsub('AXX', '', names(adf))`

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @BertMaier You have to assign it to names(df)<-

Answer (score 2):

Besides the excellent answers of akrun et. alii, the reason why your code is not working as intended is because you change the name of `df` in the scope of the function (and only there). You would need to return `df` and assign it back to the original variable:

```
replaceColNamePattern2 <- function(df, pattern, replace){
   names(df) <- gsub(pattern, replace, names(df))
   df
}

(df <- replaceColNamePattern2(df, "AXX", ""))
#   brand name production
# 1    b1 car1         10
# 2    b2 car2         10
# 3    b2 car2         10
# 4    b2 car2         40
# 5    b3 car3         10
# 6    b1 car1          5
```

Comment: Okay, then I deleted my answer (if wrapping with function is what is intended)