# modify the name of a subset of variables

Tags: r, names

I would like to modify the name of a subset of variables in a data-frame.

For example

foo <- data.frame(test.y=1:10, test.x=1:10)

How can I select all variables with ending ".y" and rename them for with ending ".z"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your example you'd have 2 columns named test.x

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493314/rename-columns-based-on-pattern-r

Comment: modified my question (...ending ".z" rather than ".x") to avoid having to variables named test.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
names(foo) <- make.unique(sub("\\.y$", ".x", names(foo)))
```